# Save button for PDFKit?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, pdfkit

Is it possible to add a save button for download in pdf with PDFkit ?

```
file = kit.to_file('/path/to/save/pdf')
```

I saw this on Github but i dont know how to do the action when push the button, the download will be launched in the browser

Thanks you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use the following link https://github.com/devongovett/pdfkit

```
# require dependencies
PDFDocument = require 'pdfkit'
blobStream  = require 'blob-stream'

# create a document the same way as above
doc = new PDFDocument

# pipe the document to a blob
stream = doc.pipe(blobStream())

# add your content to the document here, as usual

# get a blob when you're done
doc.end()
stream.on 'finish', ->
# get a blob you can do whatever you like with
blob = stream.toBlob('application/pdf')

# or get a blob URL for display in the browser
url = stream.toBlobURL('application/pdf')
iframe.src = url
```

> Above code write document into stream ( memory ), once finish stream put into blobStream and then generate url and show in iframe.
>
> When user click button, redirect to url, so they can download already

Comment: Thanks you but what should i replace "doc.end()" for obtain an event on click on a button ?

Comment: How to put a button event estead of stream.on 'finish' ?

Comment: Once pdf created you just put button.src=url, Above code is in CoffeeScript and blob-stream is nodejs module